# What is the best way to create a form with a confirmation page?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I would like to create the following form:

Step 1: The user enters his contact details.

Step 2: A confirmation page, where the user has the possibility to confirm or edit his entered data again (back to step 1)

The contact details are stored in an entity domain object. The properties have annotations for validation.

My problem:
When I pass the contact object to the confirmation page, I get the message

> Could not serialize Domain Object Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Object. It is neither an Entity with identity properties set, nor a Value Object.

I understand that I cannot pass a non-persistent domain object. A tip I found was to convert the object to an array and back again later. This works to display the input on the confirmation page. But if the user edits the data, I lose the validation functionality when converting to an array.

Another possibility would be to persist the object already after step 1 (temporarily?) . The problem here is that the data must not be displayed in the backend (they are not yet confirmed).  In addition, unused data is created if the user cancels the process.

Is it possible to save objects temporarily?

What is the most elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Anybody got any ideas? I think the case of having temporary data is more common. For example, in a shopping cart system. Where can I save the data and edit it again if necessary before it becomes persistent?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wan't to create a form, why don't you use a form plugin like Ext:form or Ext:powermail? These have a summary page by default. And you have the possibility to write the entered data into you're database.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But there is a more complex processing logic behind the confirmation. I don't think I could do this with Powermail. In my question, I have tried to isolate the problem.